# Is "alluded to previously" unfitting here?

Tags: word-choice

I am in a personal situation where I'm discussing a request that I'm making to an entity, and the reasons for that request. I discuss my reasons *somewhat at length*. (note all of this is in writing). A couple of sentences after this, I discuss a separate request, that I'm making for the same reasons as the previous one. I'm tempted to say "I'm making the same request for the same reasons *alluded to* previously."

But I am unsure if "alluded to" is appropriate here because I feel like typically when you use "alluded" it's in a situation where the thing you're "alluding" to wasn't discussed *at length*. In my situation, I do discuss the thing I'm "alluding" to somewhat at length. So because of that, would "alluded" to be inappropriate word choice here?

There's plenty of other words I could use such as "for the same reason that I discussed previously," but I am curious what others think about using "alluded" in this situation. I can see it going either way, and I've heard it used either way.

Comment: "... for the same reasons *described* previously," or "... for the same reasons as before," or just "... for the same reasons." I don't think there was any *discussion* and there is no *allusion* if you were clear, direct and specific.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes, or "for the reasons *given* previously".

Comment: What do you need *previously*? If you addressed material a minute ago, that's not previously. Previously is the past. Just because stuffed shirts previously used expressions like "as referred to above" does not make it good.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Previously in this case would be a minute ago if stated verbally, or 2 sentences ago if stated in writing. So by your definition, it's not previously. I guess it would be "just now."

Answer (score 0):

For “allude”, the OED gives

> **2.a.** *intransitive.* With to, †at, †unto, etc. Of a person: to make an oblique, covert, or indirect reference to, to refer indirectly or in passing to. **Also (esp. in later use): to refer in any manner to.**
>
> 1957   P. Wernberg-Møller Manual Discipline 135   This translation appears to suggest that the expression alludes to other members of the community of lower rank.
>
> 2003   T. Litt Finding Myself 143   This evening, when I alluded to our midnight meeting, Cecile blanked me.

Whilst your use of "**allude**" apparently fits the later/current use, it is very hard to escape the nuance that the allusion is an "oblique, covert, or indirect reference", or, at least, only briefly mentioned or mentioned as a matter of secondary interest at the time.

In your case, if the matter has been discussed in some detail and/or depth, “allude” would not be the best choice.

Comment: It's not just that *allude* 'would not be the best choice'; it would be positively misleading. Notwithstanding the bolded clause in the quotation from the OED, to allude to something is **normally** taken to imply that it is **not** stated explicitly. Its use in the OP's context could thus lead the reader to search for some reasons **other** than the ones that were explicitly stated.